# Stop outside clicks from activating modal in Gatsby - where to put 'react-outside-click-handler'?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have added a click handler so that when a user clicks outside of my modal, it closes the modal box. I am using ['react-outside-click-handler'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-outside-click-handler) in my Gatsby.js project to achieve this.

This click handler is working perfectly and closes the modal when cliked outside of the box. However, it also toggles the modal to activate if clicked anywhere on the page (when the modal is not active).

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to stop the activation of the modal whilst keeping the deactivation feature?

Perhaps I could write an if statement specifying that when the state is false, the outside clicks do not toggle the modal?

The page:

```
export default class Contact extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
  }

  modalToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal })
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className="temp_background">
        <div className="work_boxes">
          <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={this.modalToggle}>
            <button
              className="place-order"
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${work_screenshot_2})` }}
              onClick={this.modalToggle}
            />
            <Modal onClick={this.modalToggle} status={this.state.modal} />
          </OutsideClickHandler>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The modal component:

```
export default class Modal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="modal" data-status={this.props.status}>
          <div
            className="modal-left"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${work_screenshot_2})` }}
          />
          <div className="modal-right">
            <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
            <p>{this.props.description}</p>
            <button onClick={this.props.onClick} className="close">
              <span className="fa fa-close">x</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could conditionally render it but you should also look at being more explicit with your function calls here. Using a `toggleModal` call may be more concise, but being less explicit comes at a cost.

By having two separate methods: `openModal` and `closeModal`, you can more clearly see what your code is doing. Now, your `OutsideClickHandler` component ***explicitly*** closes the modal if you click outside of it. The methods additionally check to make sure the modal is opened/closed before making changes.

```
export default class Contact extends Component {
  state = {
    modal: false,
  }

  openModal = () => {
    const { modal } = this.state;
    if (!modal) {
      this.setState({ modal: true })
    }
  }

  closeModal = () => {
    const { modal } = this.state;
    if (modal) {
      this.setState({ modal: false })
    }
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className="temp_background">
        <div className="work_boxes">
          <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={this.closeModal}>
            <button
              className="place-order"
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${work_screenshot_2})` }}
              onClick={this.openModal}
            />
            <Modal onClick={this.closeModal} status={this.state.modal} />
          </OutsideClickHandler>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very informative, thank you. I should of done this explicitly in the functions :)

Answer (score 1):

You could conditionally render it:

```
render = () => {
    return (
      {this.state.modal ? (<div className="temp_background">
        <div className="work_boxes">
          <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={this.modalToggle}>
            <button
              className="place-order"
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${work_screenshot_2})` }}
              onClick={this.modalToggle}
            />
            <Modal onClick={this.modalToggle} status={this.state.modal} />
          </OutsideClickHandler>
        </div>
      </div>) : null }
    )
  }
```

As @LMulvey points out, the proper way would be to have separate open and close handlers, and it should definitely be done that way in more complicated situations. But for this simple case, a toggle is fine I think.

Comment: Thanks Will! But I'm getting a parsing error by using the above: 21:14  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","  in state.modal

Comment: should be `this.state.modal`, sorry